# external script usage in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can i use external script only with .js extensions?
Can't i use it when using the extension as .htm?

Comment: It seems to me you want to include a HTML file within an existing HTML file?

Comment: @Abkutty - is @Lloyd correct that you want to include HTML fragments? or do you just want to include dynamically generated JavaScript and thus wish to use something like `<script src="top_products.php"></script>`

Comment: @Abkutty: Then your question should be totally different: not "external script usage" but "including snippet of HTML within current page".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. What matters is the MIME type with which the script is served (by the server). It should be

```
application/javascript
```

or

```
application/x-javascript
```

This is used by certain PHP scripts that have the `.php` extension, but actually serve JavaScript (not that I like this, but it's possible).

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the extension is not important, it´s the MIME type the server serves the resource that´s important.

In practice there has existed issues with UAs from vendors (IE) that has been file extension maniacs.

Another issue is if you serve the page from the file-protocol.

So my advice, stick with `.js`

Answer (score 0):

Most jsonp is done with an external php file. Even YQL doesn't use the js extension. So yes you are able to and in fact most people do.